# Update mongoDB document with foreach of javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have this document/object in my mongoDB database and I will update **containerType** and **scheduleContainerTypeEnums** from **OVERTIME_POOL** to **SPARE_TIME**.
Therefore I tried this:

```
db.ScheduleRecordMonthCompendiumConfirmation.find().forEach(function (doc) {    
    doc.scheduleRecordDayCompendiums.forEach(function (sch) {
       sch.confirmedScheduleIntervalContainers.forEach(function (c) {
           if (c.containerType === "OVERTIME_POOL") {
               c.containerType = "ADDITIONAL_HOURS";                       
            }
        }
    });
db.ScheduleRecordMonthCompendiumConfirmation.save(doc);
});
```

But with no success. Does anyone know what I 'm doing wrong?

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57f283d4e4b039723ca44d64"),
"_class" : "mydomain.MyClass",
"scheduleRecordDayCompendiums" : [  
    {
        "_id" : null,
        "institutionUserConnectionId" : "57127240e4b0f77e64ea560e",         
        "confirmedScheduleIntervalContainers" : [
            {
                "_id" : null,
                "containerType" : "OVERTIME_POOL",              
            }           
        ],
        "scheduleContainerTypeEnums" : [
            "OVERTIME_POOL"
        ],
        ...
```

Comment: can you try printing the `doc` just before saving the same in db?

Comment: I added **print(doc);** but nothing is printed.

Comment: try `console.log(doc);`

Comment: no, nothing is printed :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript is not correctly structured. You are missing closing parenthesis for `doc.scheduleRecordDayCompendiums.forEach`

```
db.ScheduleRecordMonthCompendiumConfirmation.find().forEach(function (doc) {    
    doc.scheduleRecordDayCompendiums.forEach(function (sch) {
       sch.confirmedScheduleIntervalContainers.forEach(function (c) {
           if (c.containerType === "OVERTIME_POOL") {
               c.containerType = "ADDITIONAL_HOURS";                       
            }
        })
    });
 db.ScheduleRecordMonthCompendiumConfirmation.save(doc);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.ScheduleRecordMonthCompendiumConfirmation.find().forEach(function (doc) {    
    doc.scheduleRecordDayCompendiums.forEach(function (sch) {
       sch.confirmedScheduleIntervalContainers.forEach(function (c) {
           if (c.containerType === "OVERTIME_POOL") {
               c.containerType = "ADDITIONAL_HOURS";                       
            }
        }
    });

 doc.save(function(error){
  if(error){
    console.log(error)
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: I don't know, it seems right but it doesn't work and there is no output